# Where do uncaught local emails go?

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail, mail-command

Suppose I run -

> `mail goldfish`

There is no such account on the system and no such aliases defined, where would the mail go?

How do I see a list of such mails?

Comment: Is there a mail server running on this system? Your inclusion of dovecot is an imap server, implying that the mail might be on another system, I don't think it's needed for this Q.

Comment: @slm `dovecot` removed. I have GNU `mailutils` package on my system.

Comment: Are you using sendmail or postfix? What's the underlying distro?

Comment: @slm I think it is `postfix`. I am on `Ubuntu 13.10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email would be returned to the sender as undeliverable due to lack of a destination address by the mail daemon on the destination server.

Comment: What destination server? This is local email, from one unix account to another.

Comment: Then the local server *is* the destination server, and the bounce email will be sent to the originating account.

Comment: As the admin should I be logging into the accounts of every user to see bounced emails? How do I get them redirected to my account?

Comment: If I, as `user@example.com`, send an email to `no.such.user@example.com` (which does not exist), an email will be sent from the mail daemon to the sender (`user@example.com`) explaining why the message could not be sent using one of [these](http://www.iana.org/assignments/smtp-enhanced-status-codes/smtp-enhanced-status-codes.xhtml) codes to identify the cause. If you want to see the status of all emails handled by your server, grep the mail daemon log in `/var/log` for the status code in each message handled by the server.

Comment: @KshitizSharma: just look into /var/spool/mail/* , or `locate | egrep 'some_user_name|mbox|dead\.letter'` or do a test and look new files: `touch /tmp/NOW ; mail goldfish ; find / -newer /tmp/NOW -ls` [in case you use "exotic" mail systems... timdowtdi]

Answer (score 3):

#### No mail server running

When I attempt to construct a bogus email on my Fedora 19 system I get the following entry in my system's `/var/log/maillog`.

```
$ mail blah@localhost
Subject: test
test
.
EOT
```

Contents of `/var/log/maillog`:

```
$ more maillog
Jan  2 23:16:45 greeneggs sendmail[21847]: s034Gi1W021847: from=saml, size=209, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201401030416.s034Gi1W021847@gree
neggs.bubba.net>, relay=root@localhost
Jan  2 23:16:45 greeneggs sendmail[21847]: s034Gi1W021847: to=blah@localhost, ctladdr=saml (1000/1000), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, m
ailer=relay, pri=30209, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

This would imply to me that the mail sever never accepted the email to begin with, so it's likely being kicked back to the sender or ignored all together, going no where.

#### Mail server running

With sendmail running.

```
$ service sendmail start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  sendmail.service
```

Confirming its started:

```
$ ps -eaf | grep [s]endmail
root     22157     1  0 23:20 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: accepting connections
smmsp    22173     1  0 23:20 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
```

Repeating the same test:

```
$ mail blah@localhost
Subject: test2
test
.
EOT
```

We now get a bounced receipt from the mail server that the address doesn't exist.

```
...
The original message was received at Thu, 2 Jan 2014 23:28:37 -0500
from root@localhost

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
blah@localhost
    (reason: 550 5.1.1 <blah@greeneggs.bubba.net>... User unknown)
    (expanded from: blah@localhost)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to [127.0.0.1]:
>>> DATA
<<< 550 5.1.1 <blah@greeneggs.bubba.net>... User unknown
550 5.1.1 blah@localhost... User unknown
<<< 503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
...
```

This showed up in my user's email spool here: `/var/spool/mail/saml`.

Comment: That answers my first question. Second was - `How do I see a list of such mails?` Is it possible to configure postfix to direct all such mails to a given account?

Comment: There is no "list" as you're asking for, you'd have to configure the underlying mail server to keep a copy of any bounces, or grep through the mail server's logs for these incidents.

Comment: `configure the underlying mail server to keep a copy of any bounces` is what I'm after. But I think that one deserves a questions of its own. This one is answered.

Comment: http://amail.io/techblog/bounce-handling-with-postfix/

Comment: You may have answered my question. I get a lot of "User unknown" in sendmail maillog from outside the system but now getting a response from Google like, "stat=Deferred: 421-4.7.0 [107.XXX.XX.XXX 15] Our system has detected a
n unusual rate of", which is cut off. Is Google sending that to me or the original mailer? Am I getting myself into trouble with this (the risk of being blocked)?

Comment: @Rob - can you ask your Q as a separate one? I'm not sure i follow what you're asking me but I'm sure I can answer it.